# how to create a template for layout - static website

Tags: php, css, html

I am going to develop a static website with around 100 pages in PHP. The layout of the inner pages will remain the same. There will be a banner, an image and some text on each of these pages just like this page here (http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-clean-blog/post.html).

Now the problem is; what if later on I want to add one more images on all the pages? I will have to manually edit the html in those 100 pages by adding the img tag.

I was thinking of creating a template for the layout of the inner pages by creating some placeholders for the text, images etc. in that template file and have content for these placeholders be replaced dynamically.

How should I go about implementing this and is there any drawback for this approach?

Answer (score 1):

How about using a Template Engine? For example Smarty? http://www.smarty.net/
Here you have all functionality and also your wanted placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

MVC concept is great for that because you can manage all your page with only one controller (function php) which process the same logic with differents resources.

Also Twig is a great templating Engine : [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)

Perhaps Silex (micro framework Symfony) is a good approach for minimal MVC : [SILEX](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)